# Raml 1.0 Types with examples and mulesoft mocking service

Tags: raml

I am using RAML 1.0 in the mulesoft api designer.

I would like to use types/properties to describe my api responses, and also enable the mocking service so I can run the api and get back an example response. I thought if I gave the type an example value the mocking service would be able to generate the example json response. This is my test raml

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Test
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/<removed>

types:

  Email:
    description: Email address
    example: Steve@test.com

/user:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            properties:
              email: Email
```

When I run the api through the mocking service, I expect my response body to be this:

```
{
  "email": "Steve@test.com"
}
```

but the service reports that it has no information and returns this in the body

```
{
  "message": "RAML had no response information for application/json"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be a cool feature but it doesn't work that way.

You need to add the example in the response:

```
...
types:

  Email:
    description: Email address

/user:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            properties:
              email: Email
            example: { "email": "Steve@test.com" }
```

Comment: I want to use types to represent my database tables, and different apis can return data from more than one tables nested together, and if I have to manually create the example for each response, and then I make a change to one of my tables, I have to manually edit the responses for all the apis that use this table.

Comment: If you change your table you will have to change the example and also the type.
But yes, I see your point, it would be cool to include the example of a nested type, you could ask for that feature https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console

Comment: Yes but I'll only have to change the type and example in one place! I have opened an issue if anyone is interested: https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/302

Answer (score 0):

We need to provide the example type we are expecting, check this link http://raml.org/developers/raml-200-tutorial

below just added example in response body, there we can provide multiple outcomes to.

## %RAML 1.0

title: Test
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/

types:

Email:
    description: Email address
    example: Steve@test.com

/user:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            properties:
              email: Email
                example: 
                  "email" : [
                       { "email" :  "Steve@test.com"}
                            ]

Answer (score 0):

**Types tag in Raml 1.0 is more powerful. You have design your custom type as per comfort and also increase reputability of the code**

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Brochure
version: v1
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/63063930-851d-41cc-b021-36d8a435d800 # baseUri: http://localhost:8080
protocols: HTTP
mediaType: application/json
types:
  ModelTree:
    type: object
    properties:
      modelTreeReference: string
      brand: string
      series?: string
      constructionSeries?: string
      bodyType?: string
      AGModelCode?: string
      UKModelCode?: string
      levelCode?: number
  Brochure:
    type: object
    properties:
      recordNumber: number
      partNumber: number
      name: string
      brand: string
      brochureType: string
      CRMGroup: string
      CRMSubGroup: string
      isActiveIndicator: string
      modelTree: ModelTree
  Status:
    type: object
    properties:
      responseStatus:
        enum: [COMPLETE, ERROR, FATAL]
      responseId: number
  Transaction:
    type: object
    properties:
      status: Status
      data:
        type: object
        properties:
          brochures?: Brochure[]
/brochures:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        description: Status and a list of Brochures
        body:
          application/json:
            example: {
              status: {
                responseStatus: 'COMPLETE',
                responseId: 123
                },
              data: {
                brochures: [{
                    recordNumber: 1,
                    partNumber: 56,
                    name: "Activity Brochure",
                    brand: "My Brand Ltd",
                    brochureType: "HARDCOPY",
                    CRMGroup: "Sales",
                    CRMSubGroup: "Lifestyle/Access",
                    isActiveIndicator: "N",
                    modelTree: {
                      modelTreeReference: "My Brand",
                      brand: "My Brand Ltd",
                      levelCode: 1
                      }
                  }
                ]
                }
              }
            type: Transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using examples with a form encoded body.  The examples given in the spec and the [RAML 200 tutorial](https://raml.org/developers/raml-200-tutorial#resource-types) for application/json encoded responses don't work for application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

This type

```
types:
  hub:
    type: object
    properties:
      callback: string
      mode: 
        enum: ["subscribe", "unsubscribe"]
      topic: string
```

works properly with an application/json body and example

```
/subv1json:
  post:
    description: "Subscribes to a topic"
    body:
      application/json:
        type: hub
        example: 
          {
            "callback": "http://yourcallback.url.com",
            "mode": "subscribe",
            "topic": "orders"
          }  
    responses:
      202:
```

Returns: 202 Accepted

but changing the encoding to x-www-form-urlencoded

```
/subv1form: #this doesn't work, returns 400 bad request
  post:
    description: "Subscribes to a topic"
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        type: hub
        example: 
          {
            "callback": "http://yourcallback.url.com",
            "mode": "subscribe",
            "topic": "orders"
          } 
    responses:
      202:
```

Returns 400 Bad Request and a syntax error

```
  {
"code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
"message": "Invalid schema for content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Errors: Syntax error in the following text: '}: { "callback": "http://yourcallback.url.com", "mode": "subscribe",'. "
}
```

I found that moving the example inside of the type definition didn't help - only changed the error to a more precise 'require key [mode] not found'

```
{
"code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
"message": "Invalid schema for content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Errors: required key [mode] not found. "
}
```

However, reformatting the sample to yaml syntax does work, but requires that you do NOT specify the example in the type.

```
/subv3examplereformatted: #this works
  post:
    description: "Subscribes to a topic"
    body:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
        type: hub
        example: 
          id: "example1"
          callback: "http://yourcallback.com"
          mode: "subscribe"
          topic: "order"
    responses:
      202:
```

So, there is quirky-ness to how the mocking services manage serializing examples for form encoded parameters, and more than one way to provide examples.  This is one work around if you want to use x-www-form-urlencoded and provide examples that work in the mocking services.